# Am I informed when a documentation proposal has 5 committers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation

I've committed to https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/crontab on documentation. The proposal has 4 committers and I'd like to write something about it.

Now I've been checking every day if someone else has committed to the topic so that I can start writing an example - but am wondering if I would be informed if a proposal goes from proposal to "go and document".

If that's not the case, can it be enabled?

EDIT after the comments:

Please enable notifications.

Comment: No, I didn't get any.

Comment: There isn’t one, but you will be auto-signed up for inbox notifications when it’s enabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This already exists. When the tag is created, you'll get an inbox notification to the effect of, "crontab documentation is open for contributions".

You'll *also* be signed up for daily notifications of any requested topics, proposed changes, or requests for improvement in the tag - and upon creation, the system automatically requests improvement on the "overview" topic ("introduction to...") and the default example in it ("installation and setup"). These won't necessarily show up *immediately*, but if everyone misses the creation notification they'll come along a bit later to prod committers like yourself into action.

So you'll get plenty of heads-up.